# Converted program to use functions and now when ran does nothing

Tags: c, arrays, function, char

Ok so in this book I'm working through (trying to learn functions), my programming project was to convert a previous program I had written in a previous chapter to use functions. So I converted it, compiled it, and ran it but after the function is ran it fails to perform any of the loops within that function....so the program runs but nothing is printed in my console, just a press any key to exit.

I think that this may be related to my #define's but I'm not sure as I am still trying to learn them and the chapter seemed to indicated in one portion of code that the macros can be used throughout the program regardless of functions....correct me if I am wrong but here is the code below, I ran some tests on it and the functions are called and ran all the way through but the for loops and such fail to run my printf tests....

```
    // Chapter 9 Programming Project #3

  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdbool.h>
  3 #include <stdlib.h>
  4 #include <time.h>
  5
  6 #define SIZE 10
  7 #define PATH_SIZE 25
  8 #define ROW_SIZE ((int) (sizeof(walk) / sizeof(walk[0])))
  9
 10 void generate_random_walk(char walk[SIZE][SIZE]);
 11 void print_array(char walk[SIZE][SIZE]);
 12
 13 int main(void)
 14 {
 15         char walk[SIZE][SIZE];
 16         // Create board
 17         generate_random_walk(walk);
 18         // Print board
 19         print_array(walk);
 20         return 0;
 21 }
 22
 23 void generate_random_walk(char walk[SIZE][SIZE])
 24 {
 25         // 0 = Up, 1 = Down, 2 = Left, 3 = Right
 26         int i, x, y;
 27
 28         // Generate a random number
 29         srand((int) time(NULL));
 30         int dir = rand() % 4;
 31
 32         // Set all positions of walk to '.'
 33         for (x = 0; x < ROW_SIZE; x++) {
 34                 for (y = 0; y < ROW_SIZE; y++)
 35                         walk[x][y] = '.';
 36                 printf("Set Test: %d\n", x);
 37         }
 38         x = 0;
 39         y = 0;
 40         walk[0][0] = 'A';
 41
 42         // Generate the path
 43         for (i = 0; i < PATH_SIZE;) {
 44                 // Check that the last character has not been cornered
 45                 if ((walk[x][y - 1] != '.' || y - 1 < 0) &&
 46                                 (walk[x][y + 1] != '.' || y + 1 > ROW_SIZE) &&
 47                                 (walk[x - 1][y] != '.' || x - 1 < 0) &&
 48                                 (walk[x + 1][y] != '.' || x + 1 > ROW_SIZE))
 49                         break;
 50
 51                 // Check the direction and replace that char
 52                 switch (dir) {
 53                         case 0: if ((y - 1) >= 0
 54                                                 && walk[x][y - 1] == '.') {
 55                                         walk[x][--y] = i + 'B';
 56                                         ++i;
 57                                 } break;
 58                         case 1: if ((y + 1) < ROW_SIZE
 59                                                 && walk[x][y + 1] == '.') {
 60                                         walk[x][++y] = i + 'B';
 61                                         ++i;
 62                                 } break;
 63                         case 2: if ((x - 1) >= 0
 64                                                 && walk[x - 1][y] == '.') {
 65                                         walk[--x][y] = i + 'B';
 66                                         ++i;
 67                                 } break;
 68                         case 3: if ((x + 1) < ROW_SIZE
 69                                                 && walk[x + 1][y] == '.') {
 70                                         walk[++x][y] = i + 'B';
 71                                         ++i;
 72                                 } break;
 73                         default: if (walk[x][y] == '.')
 74                                          walk[x][y] = i + 'B';
 75                                  break;
 76                 }
 77
 78                 // Reset the random directions
 79                 dir = rand() % 4;
 80         }
 81 }
 82
 83 void print_array(char walk[SIZE][SIZE])
 84 {
 85         int x, y;
 86         // Print the walk
 87         for (x = 0; x < ROW_SIZE; x++) {
 88                 for (y = 0; y < ROW_SIZE; y++)
 89                         printf("%4c ", walk[x][y]);
 90                 printf("\n");
 91                 printf("Print Test: %d\n", x);
 92         }
 93 }
```

Just wanted to take the time to thanks everyone in this community for all the support and I hope that soon I will be able to return the favor.

Comment: Note that I did remove the printf tests statements to provide a cleaner view of my code

Comment: `ROW_SIZE` : It is not correct and should be an array of real. use the `SIZE` instead

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY, that was correct. I can't pass sizeof like that when it comes to functions, apparently you have to pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to run this, I get the following compiler warning:

```
Untitled.c:34:25: warning: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'char (*)[10]' instead of 'char [10][10]' [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
        for (x = 0; x < ROW_SIZE; x++) {
                        ^
```

I forget the details (someone please chime in if you know it), but I seem to remember something about C being weird in the way it handles arrays passed in to functions. You probably want to calculate the size of the array and pass it in to the function as an additional parameter, like this:

```
void generate_random_walk(char walk[SIZE][SIZE], int arraySize)
```

My C is a little rusty, so someone please correct my parameter syntax if I’ve missed something.

Comment: thanks, I thought that might be the problem but I wasn't sure. I'll go try that now and get back to y'all

Comment: hey @ZevEisenberg what compiler do you use?

Comment: I pasted it into a blank C file in CodeRunner, so it’s whatever that uses for the default.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so Zev Eisenberg, thanks again, here is the corrected code for anyone who may have a similar problem.

```
    // Chapter 9 Programming Project #3

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

    #define SIZE 10
    #define PATH_SIZE 25
    #define ROW_SIZE ((int) (sizeof(walk) / sizeof(walk[0])))

    void generate_random_walk(char walk[SIZE][SIZE], int arraySize);
    void print_array(char walk[SIZE][SIZE], int arraySize);

    int main(void)
    {
        char walk[SIZE][SIZE];
        int arraySize = ROW_SIZE;
        // Create board
        generate_random_walk(walk, arraySize);
        // Print board
        print_array(walk, arraySize);
        return 0;
    }

    void generate_random_walk(char walk[SIZE][SIZE], int arraySize)
    {
        // 0 = Up, 1 = Down, 2 = Left, 3 = Right
        int i, x, y;

        // Generate a random number
        srand((int) time(NULL));
        int dir = rand() % 4;

        // Set all positions of walk to '.'
        for (x = 0; x < arraySize; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < arraySize; y++)
                walk[x][y] = '.';
        }
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        walk[0][0] = 'A';

        // Generate the path
        for (i = 0; i < PATH_SIZE;) {
            // Check that the last character has not been cornered
            if ((walk[x][y - 1] != '.' || y - 1 < 0) &&
                (walk[x][y + 1] != '.' || y + 1 > arraySize) &&
                (walk[x - 1][y] != '.' || x - 1 < 0) &&
                (walk[x + 1][y] != '.' || x + 1 > arraySize))
                break;

            // Check the direction and replace that char
            switch (dir) {
                case 0: if ((y - 1) >= 0
                            && walk[x][y - 1] == '.') {
                            walk[x][--y] = i + 'B';
                            ++i;
                        } break;
                case 1: if ((y + 1) < arraySize
                            && walk[x][y + 1] == '.') {
                            walk[x][++y] = i + 'B';
                            ++i;
                        } break;
                case 2: if ((x - 1) >= 0
                            && walk[x - 1][y] == '.') {
                            walk[--x][y] = i + 'B';
                            ++i;
                        } break;
                case 3: if ((x + 1) < arraySize
                            && walk[x + 1][y] == '.') {
                            walk[++x][y] = i + 'B';
                            ++i;
                        } break;
                default: if (walk[x][y] == '.')
                             walk[x][y] = i + 'B';
                             break;
            }

        // Reset the random directions
        dir = rand() % 4;
        }
    }

    void print_array(char walk[SIZE][SIZE], int arraySize)
    {
        int x, y;
        // Print the walk
        for (x = 0; x < arraySize; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < arraySize; y++)
                printf("%4c ", walk[x][y]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```